# Setting attributes on __func__

Tags: python, function, class

In the documentation on instance methods it states that:

> Methods also support accessing (but not setting) the arbitrary function attributes on the underlying function object.

But I can't seem to be able to verify that restriction. I tried setting both an arbitrary value and one of the "Special Attributes" of functions:

```
class cls:
    def foo(self):
        f = self.foo.__func__
        f.a = "some value"  # arbitrary value
        f.__doc__ = "Documentation"
        print(f.a, f.__doc__)
```

When executed, no errors are produced and the output is as expected:

```
cls().foo() # prints out f.a, f.__doc__
```

What is it that I'm misunderstanding with the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what is being said. It says that you can access but not set the attributes of the underlying function object **from the method**!

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def foo(self):
...         self.foo.__func__.a = 1
...         print(self.foo.a)
...         self.foo.a = 2
... 
>>> Foo().foo()
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in foo
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Note how `foo.a` is updated when you set it on the `__func__` value, but you cannot set it directly using `self.foo.a = value`.

So the function object can be modified as you please, the method *wrapper* only provides read-only access to the attributes on the underlying function.

Comment: Oh damn it, silly of me. Thanks for clearing that up.